# Spark Streaming: Can I process "windows" based on an ordering of the elements?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark Streaming, currently evaluating it, coming from "plain Hadoop" and Spark batch processing. In my pipeline, I have a DStream where in each partition, the elements are guaranteed to be ordered, i.e., for each element `E(i)`, it is guaranteed that `E(i) >= E(i-k)`.

Is it possible to process such a stream in the form of "windows" so that each "window" contains elements between a rolling minimum and maximum? For example, if the DStream consists of timestamped measured values, and it is guaranteed that the timestamps appear in a rising order, that I can apply a computation on each batch of values on a hourly basis? Ideal would be to create a DStream where the RDDs inside are built this way.

Is this already possible, or how would one do that?

Comment: You can use windows functions provided by Spark and can also sort the elements in each "window" but you may not able to sort the elements across with "windows". Now the content of each window will purely depend upon the way the data is generated by Input Stream.

Comment: The data comes from Kafka, and is fed in from files, so file 1 contains data from a specific date/time range, file 2 from the next one, etc., but when I use the DStream from Kafka as-is, the times I get for the windows are from when it was fed into Kafka, not the times in the original files. Is it possible to "forge" the times when messages were posted to Kafka instead?

Comment: As far as understand you need time/ date specified in the raw files and not the time when it was posted. As of now Kafka Connectors does not provide any such functionality. Either need to modify the Kafka Consumer for achieving the same or may be write custom logic in your application job to achieve the same for example consume data and store it in any NoSQL Database (along with dates on files) and then have another job to read chunk to data based on dates for each record.